# How do you make a table read-only using ASP.NET's dynamic data scaffolding

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5, dynamic-data

How do you make individual tables and/or columns read-only so the edit button won't show in ASP.NET's Dynamic Data framework?

I'm using it against an entity data context.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my article here [Making a Field Read-Only via the ReadOnlyAttribute – Dynamic Data](http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2009/01/making-field-read-only-via.html) should get you what you want.